# Unable to find API's for BigQuery Routine using Node Module

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am unable to find any operations related to 'Routine' using Node library. I don't see any note in official documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/bigquery. Can someone please let me know any link which mentions Node library doesn't supports 'Routines'

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/src/routine.ts

Comment: Thanks Graham, I am facing similar  issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672373/creating-routine-using-google-big-query-client-returns-callback-is-not-a-funct while create Routine, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to visit official BigQuery API [routines documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/routines), where you can read more about following methods:

- delete
- get
- insert
- list
- update

Additionally, you can call this method on live data by typing `projectId`, `datasetId`, `routineId`. It will allow you to see the API request and response.

Moreover, to find examples of using specific routine methods: `create`, `delete`, `exists`, `get`, `getMetadata`, `setMetadata`, please have a look at [Google BigQuery Client Library for Node.js](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Routine.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks Muscat, I am facing issue similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672373/creating-routine-using-google-big-query-client-returns-callback-is-not-a-funct to create routine, any idea what is going wrong

Comment: In reference to your new error, I would like to encourage you to ask new question, providing the code and the full error message. We'll be able to help :)

Comment: Hi Muscat, please check  post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672373/creating-routine-using-google-big-query-client-returns-callback-is-not-a-funct. Code is provided there, I am using same code from documentation