# Creating routine using google big query client returns 'callback' is not a function error

Tags: google-bigquery

Using google biq query client i am trying to run create routine function but it is failing with callback is not a  function error

```
 const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')
    const projectId = 'bigqueryproject1-279307'
    const keyFilename = '../credentials/client_secrets.json'
    const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery({ projectId, keyFilename })
    const dataset = bigqueryClient.dataset('babynames')
    const routine = dataset.routine('analysis_routine')
    
    async function createRoutine () {
      const config = {
        arguments: [{
          name: 'x',
          dataType: {
            typeKind: 'INT64'
          }
        }],
        definitionBody: 'x * 3',
        routineType: 'SCALAR_FUNCTION',
        returnType: {
          typeKind: 'INT64'
        }
      }
      const [routine1, apiResponse] = await routine.create(config)
      console.log('*******apiResponse*****', apiResponse)
      console.log('****routine1*********', routine1)
    }
    createRoutine()
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

See this [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/issues/806) filed against repository